# How to add toolbar to java text hover eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, hover

I am tring to create my own text hover plugin for eclipse.
I success to write my own code in my hover, but I try to add a toolbar to the hover (inside the new tooltip opened).
I read that I need to use the getHoverControlCreator function, and I managed to add the toolbar manager that I see when the text hover is opened while running the plugin,in the debbuger I can see that the ToolBarManger has the ToolBar that has the ToolItems, but I can't see them in the real text hover when I opened it.

this is my code:

```
public IInformationControlCreator getHoverControlCreator() {
        return new IInformationControlCreator() {
            public IInformationControl createInformationControl(Shell parent) {
                ToolBar tb = new ToolBar(parent, SWT.HORIZONTAL);
                ToolBarManager tbm = new ToolBarManager(tb);
                DefaultInformationControl dic = new DefaultInformationControl(parent, tbm);
                ToolItem ti = new ToolItem(tb, SWT.PUSH);
                ti.setText("hello");
    tb.update();
    tb.redraw();
    tbm.update(true);
    parent.update();
    parent.redraw();

    parent.layout();

                return dic;
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what one of the Eclipse hover controls does:

```
@Override
public IInformationControl doCreateInformationControl(Shell parent) {
    ToolBarManager tbm = new ToolBarManager(SWT.FLAT);

    DefaultInformationControl iControl = new DefaultInformationControl(parent, tbm);

    IAction action = new MyAction();
    tbm.add(action);

    tbm.update(true);

    return iControl;
}
```

So it does not create the `ToolBar` - leave that up to `DefaultInformationControl`. It uses an `Action` in the tool bar and adds it after creating the DefaultInformationControl. It just calls `update(true)` at the end.

(This is a modified version of parts of `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.NLSStringHover`)

`MyAction` would be something like:

```
private class MyAction extends Action
{
  MyAction()
  {
    super("Title", .. image descriptor ..);

    setToolTipText("Tooltip");
  }

  @Override
  public void run()
  {
    // TODO your code for the action
  }
}
```

Comment: OpenPropertiesFileAction  is another inner class of NLSStringHover that I cannot use. Do you have any suggestions how to use this code in my project?

Comment: That is just an `Action` - you can write your own class extending `Action`. Changed example not to reference that class

Comment: Thanks It really add the action to the tbm, but there is another problem. When I try to click on the action it is available for second +- and than all the ToolBarManger is disappeared

Comment: Sorry but that is as much as I know about this.

Comment: First of all thanks for your help, Second I ment that if I move the mouse to the ToolBarManager it disappear after some moments. It doesn't matter if I add an action to the tbm or just add text instead of the TBM do you have any idea why the texthover "throw" the ToolBarManager or the text I give to him? If I give a beckground color for example the color disappear too